# Flask SMTP authentication error

Tags: python, email, smtp, flask, flask-mail

I am having issues in adding a contact page to a webpage. I am using Flask to do this.
The section I dont understand is this:

```
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 465
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = '''example@gmail.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';
r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;
s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);
l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>]'''

app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'password'
```

and

```
msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='''contact@gmail.com<script
type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';
r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;
s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);
l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>', recipients=['example@gmail.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';
r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;
s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);
l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>]''')
```

Please explain which email address should I put at the following places in the code, where should i add my email id? and what should the other one be. I do not have my own domain.

```
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = '''example@gmail.com
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'password'

msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='''contact@gmail.com
recipients=['example@gmail.com . .
```

Comment: I am referring this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial seems a little overcomplicated. Not sure why you would need all that Javascript. Here is what works for me which I have tested:

Config settings for gmail should be something like:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

In code above, replace the `app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']` with your actual gmail address. Same for password. Using this settings, the email will be sent from your gmail account to the receiver. All this information above is for the sender i.e. your gmail account.

Then, to send the email, just do the following

```
msg = Message(subject,sender="sender@gmail.com",recipients=['user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com'])
msg.body = "test email"
mail.send(msg)
```

In the above code, replace `recipient`s with whoever you want to send the email to. recipients is a list. So you can enter 1 or more email address as needed.

Finally, using the above 2, flask-mail will send an email from sender@gmail.com (i.e. you) to user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com etc. (i.e. the receiver)

Comment: Thanks a lot,you explained it clearly. This worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure "Access for less secure apps has been turned on" for your google account. Else that can cause SMTP Authentication problems.
You can turn on/off from google settings:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

make sure in security section in your gmail account access to less secure apps has been turned on